# ListView istead of *ngFor

Tags: listview, nativescript, scrollview

I use a ScrollView for a Chat-Overview in NativeScript.

I used this code for the Scrollview until now:

```
<ScrollView #scrollLayout style="height: 80%;margin-top: -200px">

   <StackLayout class="chat-body">
        <StackLayout *ngFor="let message of messages"  orientation="vertical">

                <Label *ngIf="message.sender == me" horizontalAlignment="right" class="chat-message-me" [text]="message.msg"></Label>
                <Label *ngIf="message.sender == me" horizontalAlignment="right" class="chat-timestamp" [text]="message.time"></Label>
            
                <Label *ngIf="message.sender != me" horizontalAlignment="left" class="chat-message-you" [text]="message.msg"></Label>
                <Label *ngIf="message.sender != me" horizontalAlignment="left" class="chat-timestamp" [text]="message.time"></Label>
        
        </StackLayout> 
    </StackLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

It worked, but when i added a new element to the messages array the view would load the complete array on top of the already showing array.

Message Array:

[image: ![```]

View of Chat:

[image]

So my Solution was to use a ListView, like this:

```
<ScrollView #scrollLayout style="height: 80%;margin-top: -200px">
    <GridLayout class="chat-body">
        <ListView [items]="messages" orientation="vertical">
            <ng-template let-item="message">
                
                <Label *ngIf="message.sender == me" horizontalAlignment="right" class="chat-message-me" [text]="message.msg"></Label>
                <Label *ngIf="message.sender == me" horizontalAlignment="right" class="chat-timestamp" [text]="message.time"></Label>
            
                <Label *ngIf="message.sender != me" horizontalAlignment="left" class="chat-message-you" [text]="message.msg"></Label>
                <Label *ngIf="message.sender != me" horizontalAlignment="left" class="chat-timestamp" [text]="message.time"></Label>

                
            </ng-template>
        </ListView>
   </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But i get this Error:

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method getView failed
System.err: Error: No suitable views found in list template! Nesting level: 0
System.err:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ListView` automatically scrolls, so you shouldn't need a `ScrollView` parent.

The error you are seeing is because the `ListView` requires a single component/layout inside it (where you have the 4 labels).

To fix the error you could wrap your labels inside a `ContentView` or a layout like so:

```html
<ListView [items]="messages" orientation="vertical">
  <ng-template let-message="item">
    <ContentView>
      <Label *ngIf="message.sender == me" horizontalAlignment="right" class="chat-message-me" [text]="message.msg"></Label>
      <Label *ngIf="message.sender == me" horizontalAlignment="right" class="chat-timestamp" [text]="message.time"></Label>      
      <Label *ngIf="message.sender != me" horizontalAlignment="left" class="chat-message-you" [text]="message.msg"></Label>
      <Label *ngIf="message.sender != me" horizontalAlignment="left" class="chat-timestamp" [text]="message.time"></Label>
    </ContentView>
  </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

However, using `ngIf`s inside a `ListView` has some performance impacts. If possible, use multiple item templates instead. This [blog post](https://medium.com/@alexander.vakrilov/faster-nativescript-listview-with-multiple-item-templates-8f903a32e48f) has some indepth comparison between the two approaches.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but if i do it like that, the labels cant recognize name and sender. This error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" and "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sender' of undefined"

Comment: I think the undefined error is because of `let-item`. Try changing it to `let-message="item"`. @SwaX